# not able to get focus on input element of the dialog when i click on openDialog button. focus is stayed on the openDialog button

Tags: angular, angular-material

Below is the dialog config. If I remove viewContainerRef from the config, then only I am able to solve this issue. What would be the cause?

```
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(myDialog, {
    width: this.width,
    viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef,
    direction: 'ltr',
    panelClass: 'my-dialog',
    data: {
        address: this.addressResponse
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `autoFocus` option which will set the first focusable element on the dialog.

```
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(myDialog, {
    autoFocus: true,  // <-- add this here
    width: this.width,
    viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef,
    direction: 'ltr',
    panelClass: 'my-dialog',
    data: {
       address: this.addressResponse
    }
});
```